# How to use JavaScriptExecutor to get the text that appear on Browser's Status Bar

Tags: javascript, selenium

Sorry I can't put the picture in. So the Status bar is the little box on the bottom left of the browser and it appears when you hover on an web-element or on page loading.

I have tried the following:

```
.getJavascriptExecutor().executeScript("return window.status;"));
```

...but it is not working.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've conducted this little experiment, both in FF and Chrome. I executed this at the console:

```
var mine = setInterval(function () { console.log("status:", window.status); }, 
                       1000);
```

Then I hovered over links. The status output to the console was always the empty string. (Yes, I checked that it is an empty string and not something else that happens to print like an empty string.)

Your problem is not with your call to `.executeScript` but that `window.status` just does not appear to be well supported.

Comment: Thanks so much, i get an empty string in my code too. I guess this information is not available for some reason. and i'm currently try to find out why